# Get all parameters after action in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

When I call a router like below in Zend:

`coupon/index/search/cat/1/page/1/x/111/y/222`

And inside the controller when I get `$this->_params`, I get an array:

```
array(
    'module' => 'coupon',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'search',
    'cat' => '1',
    'page' => '1',
    'x' => '111',
    'y' => '222'
)
```

But I want to get only:

```
array(
    'cat' => '1',
    'page' => '1',
    'x' => '111',
    'y' => '222'
)
```

Could you please tell me a way to get the all the `params` just after the `action`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you will always get the controller, action and module in the params list as it is part of the default. You could do something like this to remove the three from the array you get:

```
    $url_params = $this->getRequest()->getUserParams();
    if(isset($url_params['controller']))
        unset($url_params['controller']);
    if(isset($url_params['action']))
        unset($url_params['action']);
    if (isset($url_params['module']))
        unset($url_params['module']);
```

Alternatively as you don't want to be doing that every time you need the list, create a helper to do it for you, something like this:

```
class Helper_Myparams extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public $params;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $this->params = $request->getParams();
    }

    public function myparams()
    {       
        if(isset($this->params['controller']))
            unset($this->params['controller']);
        if(isset($this->params['action']))
            unset($this->params['action']);
        if (isset($this->params['module']))
            unset($this->params['module']);
        return $this->params;
    }

    public function direct()
    {
        return $this->myparams();
    }
}
```

And you can simply call this from your controller to get the list:

```
$this->_helper->myparams();
```

---

So for example using the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/testing/urls/cat/1/page/1/x/111/y/222
```

And the code:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->_helper->myparams());
echo "</pre>";
```

I get the following array printed:

```
Array
(
    [cat] => 1
    [page] => 1
    [x] => 111
    [y] => 222
)
```

Comment: why there is a need to write a helper if `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` return the expected value?

Comment: Because, if you read the posters question, it does not return the expected values, the poster __does not__ want the controller, action and module in the array. `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` __WILL__ return them in its array. Hence removing them with `unset` - but if the array is going to be used either several times, or in different controllers, it is easier to use a helper and less code in the controller.

Answer (score 10):

IMHO this is more elegant and includes changes in action, controller and method keys.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$diffArray = array(
    $request->getActionKey(),
    $request->getControllerKey(),
    $request->getModuleKey()
);
$params = array_diff_key(
    $request->getUserParams(),
    array_flip($diffArray)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

In controller:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
unset($params['module'];
unset($params['controller'];
unset($params['action'];
```

Pretty clunky; might need some `isset()` checks to avoid warnings; could jam this segment into its own method or helper. But it would do the job, right?

Comment: See @Scoobler's answer, which nicely fills in the details to which I allude.